# Cannot get JWT token in middleware

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, middleware

I am trying to use JWT tokens in a project I am working on at the moment. I am trying to use a middleware to verify the JWT token before passing it to the next handler. However, I have a weird issue that I do not get the JWT token in the middleware, but if I pass it to the next handler I get the token. Hopefully the example below will explain it:

I have implemented a PING method and some logging to show you what happens. My setup looks like so:

```
this._express.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('AUTH');
    return jwt.verify(req.headers['x-access-token'], 'mysecret', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
            return false;
        }

        console.log('DECODED');
        return next();
    });
});

//Health Check
this._express.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`PING`);
    return res.status(200).send('pong');
});
```

If I execute this piece of code the output is:

```
node_1        | AUTH
node_1        | ERROR: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
```

However, if I use the next() callback in the middleware:

```
this._express.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('AUTH');
    next(); // This is the only thing that is different
    return jwt.verify(req.headers['x-access-token'], 'mysecret', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`);
            return false;
        }

        console.log('DECODED');
        return next();
    });
});

//Health Check
this._express.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`PING`);
    return res.status(200).send('pong');
});
```

The output is the following:

```
node_1        | AUTH
node_1        | ERROR: JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
node_1        | AUTH
node_1        | PING
node_1        | DECODED
```

I don't have much experience with JWT tokens, and please excuse me if it is something obvious.

Comment: In the line `jwt.verify` you have a **return**, try removing it, and just keep the return false and return next()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to find what the issue was. The problem lies with CORS. In particular, the middleware works as expected however due to CORS a preflight request is sent which does not have the JWT token which is why I got the error in the first example. I have updated the middleware to skip the preflight requests:

```
    if (req.headers['access-control-request-headers'] === 'x-access-token') {
        return next();
    }
    [...]
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is a place to make a change in code? ;) For example, when you provide malformed input in some way...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this to be a problem of `req.headers['x-access-token']`. Once `next()` is called, the control goes to the next endpoint route. You should provide JWT as initials to the token.